# При компиялиции возникает ошибка java: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

Начал с недавнего времени изучать Java. Пишу код по примерам из задач на Habr (задача по заполнению массива случайными числами), все проверил перед и после компиляции, однако возникает одна и та же ошибка. Извините, если что, за банальный вопрос, просто только начал изучать, еще совсем чайник, поэтому хотелось бы узнать, почему не проходит компиляция. Спасибо[![java: illegal start of expression][1]]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int n = 100;
double[] array = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Math.random();
}

double max = array[0];
double min = array[0];
double avg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(max < array[i])
        max = array[i];
    if(min > array)[i])
        min = array[i];
    avg += array[i]/array.length;
}

System.out.println("max = " + max);
System.out.println("min = " + min);
System.out.println("avg = " + avg);
```

}

Comment: Блин, ну там даже подсвечено жёлтым!

Comment: А что конкретно там нужно исправить-то? Я вот этого и понять не могу

Comment: Код в следующий раз выкладывай текстом, а на картинкой.

Comment: `if(min > array)[i])` посчитайте скобочки в этой строке.

Comment: Все заработало, благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Вот это:

```
if(min > array)[i])
```

Не знаю, почему компилируется, не должно. В любом случае вы не можете вытащить значение из ячейки `boolean`, хотя бы потому что `boolean` - не массив.

Какой IDE вы пользуетесь? Если не блокнотом, то такие вещи как правило подсвечиваются. А ещё при попытке запустить программу я лично получил такое сообщение:

```
Main.java:24: error: illegal start of expression
    if(min > array)[i])
                   ^
Main.java:24: error: not a statement
    if(min > array)[i])
                    ^
Main.java:24: error: ';' expected
    if(min > array)[i])
```

Читайте ошибку, если она вылезла. Так обычно всё уже расписано.

Comment: По поводу IDE - Iintellij

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что я в конце забыл скобки закрыть, после увидел, что то место подсвечивалось, просто не очень внимательно посмотрел

Comment: @ИльяСосновский в ней всё должно быть подсвечено. Обращайте внимание на жёлтые и красные полоски справа. Обращайте внимание на красные подчёркивания и жёлтые выделения кода.

Comment: @ИльяСосновский я знаю. Я об этом вам и написал.

Comment: Спасибо большое!